# Selecting all records that begin with the a particular letter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a mySQL statement that will select all records that begin with a particular letter.

For example, select all product names that being with letter 'A'.

This is what I would like the results set to be like:

```
result[0] = "Awesome Bracelets";
result[1] = "Abalone Earrings";
result[2] = "Aloe Gel";
result[3] = "Amscot Figure";
```

I would **not** want the following result to be included:

```
result[3] = "Basic Ashtray";
```

This is what I tried, though it seems to return mixed results where some of the prod_name records do not have any words that start with an 'A':

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE '%A'"
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Your query shows rows where `prod_name`  **ends** with `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost right

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE 'A%'"
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I needed! thank you! can't believe I didn't catch that :)

Comment: the issue with that approach is that it ignores values that start with an accented A... how can i include values that also start with accented letters of the same letter?